# Duplicate each row in a data frame a number of times equal to how many times a value in that row shows up in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I apologize as I wasn't quite sure how to word my question without making it extremely lengthy, as the duplicate rows also need to have some altered values from the original.

I have two data frames. The first, df1, records all paths actually taken from source to destination, while the second, df2, contains all possible paths. Some sample data is below:

### df1

| Row | Source | Destination | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 10010101 |
| 2 | A | D | 11101011 |
| 3 | A | B | 10111111 |
| 4 | E | B | 01100110 |

### df2

| Row | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | B | A |
| 3 | B | C |
| 4 | B | E |
| 5 | B | F |
| 6 | A | D |
| 7 | D | A |
| 8 | D | C |
| 9 | D | H |

For my data, it is assumed that if an object takes a path A -> B for example, it also takes every possible path stemming from B that isn't to the original source (Think of a networking hub. In one way, and out every other). So since we have a payload that goes from A -> B, I also need to record that same payload going from B to C, E, and F. I'm currently accomplishing this in the FOR loop below, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it, preferably one that doesn't use looping. I'm also somewhat new to R, so even simple corrections to my code are also appreciated.

```
for (row in 1:dim(df1)[1]){
  initialSource <- df1$source[row]     #saves the initial source
  paths <- df1[row,]         #saves the current row for duplication
  paths <- paths[rep(1, times = count(df2[df2$source %in% df1$destination[row], ])[[1]]), ]     #duplicates the row
  paths$source <- paths$destination     #replaces the source values to be the location of the hub
  paths$destination <- df2$destination[df2$source %in% paths$destination]     #replaces the destination values to be every connection from the hub
  paths <- paths[!(paths$destination %in% initialSource), ]      #removes the row that would indicate data being sent back to the source
  masterdf <- rbind(masterdf, paths)     #saving the new data to a larger data frame that df1 is actually a sample of. 
}
```

The data frame `paths` by the end of the first loop with the above data would look like:

| Row | Source | Destination | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | C | 10010101 |
| 2 | B | E | 10010101 |
| 3 | B | F | 10010101 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try merging your two dataframes. With base R `merge` you could do the following (using "Destination" from `df1` and "Source" from `df2`). You would need to remove rows to exclude the "original source" as you described. Renaming and selecting the columns gives you the final output. Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
d <- subset(
  merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Destination", by.y = "Source", all = TRUE),
  Source != Destination.y
)

data.frame(
  Source = d$Destination,
  Destination = d$Destination.y,
  Payload = d$Payload
)
```

**Output**

```
   Source Destination  Payload
1       B           C 10010101
2       B           E 10010101
3       B           F 10010101
4       B           C 10111111
5       B           E 10111111
6       B           F 10111111
7       B           C  1100110
8       B           F  1100110
9       B           A  1100110
10      D           C 11101011
11      D           H 11101011
```

Comment: That is way more elegant than what I was trying to do. Thank you! One correction though - You did it correctly in your code, but in your explanation in your parentheses, it's **"Destination"** from df1 and **"Source"** from df2.

Comment: @RoughRider1 Thanks - I corrected the answer. Glad it was helpful!